# Bamboo can't execute a command starting with "./" after upgrading to 5.4

Tags: bamboo

Bamboo is running on a Windows Server 2008 box.

We were on Bamboo 5.0.1 and I upgraded to 5.4.3. We have several jobs using Grails Wrapper and Gradle Wrapper. There are Executables registered in Bamboo of `./grailsw` and `./gradle`. These worked perfectly on the old version but after the upgrade the jobs are failing with the following error:

```
Failing task since return code of [./gradlew clean build] was -1 while expected 0
```

I've tried changing `./` to `.\` and removing it entirely and all of those fail with the same message above. If I `cd` into the build directory and run the command with either `.\` or just `gradlew` then it works fine.

When I'm running these commands I'm logged in as the same user that the service is running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Atlassian Support about this issue and it was discovered that if you're using the newer version of Bamboo on Windows it won't execute a file that doesn't have an extension.